# Why does my javascript not work correctly with razor?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

My code below doesn't work properly. I want my variable `j` to count +1 everytime in the for loop. But when i run the code its stays on 0.

**Can somebody please help me and tell me what i've done wrong?**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
        var columnChosen = [];
        @{  var j = 0;} // <---- this stays at 0.
        var count = document.getElementsByTagName("select");

        for (i = 0; i < count.length; i++)
        {
            dropdownlists.push(document.getElementById("Merchant" + i.toString()).value);
            if (dropdownlists[i] != "-- Select an attribute --") {

                temp = "@Model.Columns[j].ToString()";
                columnChosen.push(temp);
                @{j++} // <-- doesnt work why ?
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Because razor code is server side code (its evaluated on the server befaore its sent to the view) and javascript is client side code

Comment: You cannot mix Razor code and JS like you are doing. But I do not see any need for you to do that. You can just use JS variables.

Comment: Create a JS event based on the dropdown to accomplish your iteration.

Comment: Okay. I'm new to this didn't know how it worked. Thanks !